# Trouble with converting Modular Multiplicative Inverse function into an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am attempting to make a cryptographic calculator for things like ceasar, multiplicative, and linear ciphers. I made a function that can calculate a modular multiplicative inverse: `=IF(ABS(E2)=1,0,SIGN(E2)*MATCH(1,INDEX(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ABS(E2)))*SIGN(E2)*L1,ABS(E2)),0),0))`

E2 is the modulo and L1 is the multiplier/key I'm getting the inverse from. I want to make this function so that it can take an array of multipliers/keys and output an array of their multiplicative inverses. I tried doing L:L but that just put out an error, then I tried using the `SPLIT()` command and listing each cell of the array in column L(L1&L2, etc.), but that just added them together in mod E2(29). I also don't think an approach like this would work due to the fact that the length of the array in column L can be any length and I cant make a formula automatically adjust itself to list each cell in the column L array. If it helps I am also using a custom function pulled from a different question on here called `REPEAT(range/array,# of times to repeat)` and all it does is repeat an array a number of times downward.

I can't think of much else to do, so if anybody knows any function I might be missing that could make this work, I would greatly appreciate it if you'd share them. Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to list the code for the custom `REPEAT()` function so here it is.

```
  function REPEAT(range,amount,header) {
  var output = [];

  // check if range is cell
  if(typeof range == 'string') {
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      output.push([range]);
    }
    return output;
  } else {
    // check if header is wanted
    var value;
    if(header == 1) {
      output.push(range[0]);
      value=header;
    } else if(header == "") {
      value=0;
    } else {
      value=0;
    }  
    for(var i=0; i<amount; i++) {
      for(var j=value, jLen=range.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        output.push(range[j]);
      }
    }    
    return output;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with input and desired output.

Comment: @Twilight Sure! To edit it you are going to want to make a copy of it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Xc-_H0CvC28KeIXFfoXQMBEtbW-54dRXLZK6a_yUpY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to add the REPEAT function to not get the name errors btw, forgot to mention it.